# Does $\tan\left(\frac{5\pi}{4}-\alpha\right)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\alpha\right)$ hold for any angle, or only when $\pi/4-\alpha$ is acute?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, angle

I often find this in math problems, but authors don't make it clear if $\alpha$ needs to be an acute angle or not, so I am confused a little bit. I thought we can only do this kind of transformation if we know that $\frac{\pi}{4}-\alpha$ is less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$. So, my question is why is this true for any angle (if it is)?
$$\tan\left(\frac{5\pi}{4}-\alpha\right)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\alpha\right)$$

Comment: I hope trigonometry angels exist in real world.

Comment: Please learn the related trig for all angles. Nothing happens to tan value when any multiple of $\pi$ is added or removed from the angle.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $\dfrac{5\pi}{4}$ as $\pi+\dfrac\pi4$.

Thus, $\tan(\dfrac{5\pi}{4}-\alpha) = \tan(\pi+\dfrac\pi4-\alpha) = \tan(\dfrac\pi4-\alpha)$

Because for any $\alpha$
 ; $\quad$$\tan(\pi+\alpha ) = \tan(\alpha)$ .

This is also true for $\cot(\pi+\alpha)$ as both.

EDIT : 
When you have $\frac\pi2\pm\alpha $ or $\frac{3\pi}2\pm \alpha$

$\cos \to \sin$

$\tan \to \cot$

$\sec \to \csc$

and vice versa.ie if you have $\cos(\frac\pi2- \frac\pi4) $ it becomes $\sin(\frac\pi4)$

You might find it useful to learn this.

[image]

Depending on where your angle lies you should change the sign.

**Edit:** A full list of this type of identity for the non-hyperbolic trigonometric functions can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Shifts_and_periodicity).

Comment: Look this: $\cos(\frac{5\pi}{4}+\alpha)=-cos(\frac{\pi}{4}+\alpha)$, I put minus near cos, because cos is negative in the third quadrant, but how can I be sure that $\frac{\pi}{4}-\alpha$ is less than 90 degrees so it can be in the third quadrant, is this the reson why we put minus there or not?

Comment: The reason why $\cos(\frac{5\pi}4+\alpha) = -\cos(\frac\pi4+\alpha)$  is because $\pi  + a$ for any principle angle $a$ lies  in the third quadrant where $\cos(x),\sin(x)$ are negative.

Comment: $\cos(\pi + \alpha +  \frac{\pi}{4} )$ let's $\alpha=\pi$ therefore $\cos(2\pi + \frac{\pi}{4})=\cos \frac{\pi}{4}$ and now we dont have a minus near cos and we used a principle angle as you say

Comment: I meant $\alpha\in\{0,\frac\pi2\}$. but i admit you have me stumped . I'll wait for someone to check my work.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for tangent of sum is

$$ \tan(x+y)= \frac {\tan x + \tan y}{1- \tan x \tan y}$$

We know that $\tan \pi =0$

Let $x=\pi$ and $y=\pi /4 - \alpha $

You get $$ \tan(\dfrac{5\pi}{4}-\alpha) = \tan(\dfrac\pi4-\alpha)$$

Comment: Pls see comments of the other answer.